# Hash Tables for BASH

Tags: bash, ubuntu, hashtable

For every Terminal session HASH Tabels are generated . Are they stored in a file in ubuntu if so what is the location of that file which has hash tables for a particular session.

Comment: Everything is a file!

Comment: I do know that everything is a file in ubuntu , what was the location of that file , does it exist after the session is closed or it's deleted after the end of the session ??

Comment: What "hash tabels" are you referring to?

Comment: when we enter a command in the terminal  , before it get's executed it goes through aliases -> shell functions -> hash tables -> PATH , so i refer to hashtables in this flow ,  here the PATH is cached in the hash tables , i refer to that hashtable

Comment: They are not stored as files.

Comment: Then where are they stored ??  in what form ?? @rici

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables are stored as a binary structure in the shell's virtual memory (the heap), i.e. they are recreated each time you create a shell process.

The hash table guts is in `hashlib.c`, the hash command itself is implemented in `hashcmd.c`.

You can store the hash table as a set of commands in a file for later use using:

```
hash -l > hashcmds         # Or any such filename
```

The option is lower-case ell (not one).  You could put that command in your `~/.bash_logout`.

Restore with:

```
. hashcmds
```

You could put that command in your `~/.bashrc`.
The filename `hashcmds` is just something I made up - you can call it what you want.

Comment: can i be able to view these files like hashcmd.c  and its contents if so can u give the location of these files  ?  @cdarke

Comment: These are the C source code files of bash itself.   The source code is available here:  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/.   Although the code is well written, you will need a through understanding of the C programming language, and I have to wonder why you need to know the internal structure of the hash tables.

Comment: just out of intrest thnx anyways :) @cdarke

Comment: Fair enough.  Hash tables are "fun".  Note though the implementation could change between releases.